# preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in db:seed?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

Im trying to add in seed categories and translations, but im getting this error? Any suggestion how can i fix this? So what im trying is to every category add two translations.

```
public function run()
    {
      $now = Carbon::now('utc')->toDateTimeString();

      DB::table('category_translations')->delete();
      DB::table('categories')->delete();

      $arg1 = [
        [

          'slug' => 'Kreis-1-Altstadt',
          'status' => 1,
          'created_at' => $now,
          'updated_at' => $now
        ],
        [
          'slug' => 'Kreis-2',
          'status' => 1,
          'created_at' => $now,
          'updated_at' => $now
        ],
        [
          'slug' => 'Kreis-3',
          'status' => 1,
          'created_at' => $now,
          'updated_at' => $now
        ],
        [
          'slug' => 'Kreis-4',
          'status' => 1,
          'created_at' => $now,
          'updated_at' => $now
        ],
        [
          'slug' => 'Kreis-5-Industriequartier',
          'status' => 1,
          'created_at' => $now,
          'updated_at' => $now
        ],
        [
          'slug' => 'Kreis-6',
          'status' => 1,
          'created_at' => $now,
          'updated_at' => $now
        ],
        [
          'slug' => 'Kreis-7',
          'status' => 1,
          'created_at' => $now,
          'updated_at' => $now
        ],
        [
          'slug' => 'Kreis-8-Reisbach',
          'status' => 1,
          'created_at' => $now,
          'updated_at' => $now
        ],
        [
          'slug' => 'Kreis-9',
          'status' => 1,
          'created_at' => $now,
          'updated_at' => $now
        ],
        [
          'slug' => 'Kreis-10',
          'status' => 1,
          'created_at' => $now,
          'updated_at' => $now
        ],
        [
          'slug' => 'Kreis-11',
          'status' => 1,
          'created_at' => $now,
          'updated_at' => $now
        ],
        [
          'slug' => 'Kreis-12-Schwamendingen',
          'status' => 1,
          'created_at' => $now,
          'updated_at' => $now
        ]
      ];
      $category = Categories::create($arg1);

      $arg2 = [
        [
          'title' => 'Kreis 1 / Altstadt',
          'language_id' => 1,
          'category_id' => 1,
          'created_at' => $now,
          'updated_at' => $now
        ],
        [
          'title' => 'Kreis 1 / Altstadt',
          'language_id' => 2,
          'category_id' => 1,
          'created_at' => $now,
          'updated_at' => $now
        ],
        [
          'title' => 'Kreis 2',
          'language_id' => 1,
          'category_id' => 2,
          'created_at' => $now,
          'updated_at' => $now
        ],
        [
          'title' => 'Kreis 2',
          'language_id' => 2,
          'category_id' => 2,
          'created_at' => $now,
          'updated_at' => $now
        ],
        [
          'title' => 'Kreis 3',
          'language_id' => 1,
          'category_id' => 3,
          'created_at' => $now,
          'updated_at' => $now
        ],
        [
          'title' => 'Kreis 3',
          'language_id' => 2,
          'category_id' => 3,
          'created_at' => $now,
          'updated_at' => $now
        ],
        [
          'title' => 'Kreis 4',
          'language_id' => 1,
          'category_id' => 4,
          'created_at' => $now,
          'updated_at' => $now
        ],
        [
          'title' => 'Kreis 4',
          'language_id' => 2,
          'category_id' => 4,
          'created_at' => $now,
          'updated_at' => $now
        ],
        [
          'title' => 'Kreis 5 / Industriequartier',
          'language_id' => 1,
          'category_id' => 5,
          'created_at' => $now,
          'updated_at' => $now
        ],
        [
          'title' => 'Kreis 5 / Industriequartier',
          'language_id' => 2,
          'category_id' => 5,
          'created_at' => $now,
          'updated_at' => $now
        ],
        [
          'title' => 'Kreis 6',
          'language_id' => 1,
          'category_id' => 6,
          'created_at' => $now,
          'updated_at' => $now
        ],
        [
          'title' => 'Kreis 6',
          'language_id' => 2,
          'category_id' => 6,
          'created_at' => $now,
          'updated_at' => $now
        ],
        [
          'title' => 'Kreis 7',
          'language_id' => 1,
          'category_id' => 7,
          'created_at' => $now,
          'updated_at' => $now
        ],
        [
          'title' => 'Kreis 7',
          'language_id' => 2,
          'category_id' => 7,
          'created_at' => $now,
          'updated_at' => $now
        ],
        [
          'title' => 'Kreis 8 / Reisbach',
          'language_id' => 1,
          'category_id' => 8,
          'created_at' => $now,
          'updated_at' => $now
        ],
        [
          'title' => 'Kreis 8 / Reisbach',
          'language_id' => 2,
          'category_id' => 8,
          'created_at' => $now,
          'updated_at' => $now
        ],
        [
          'title' => 'Kreis 9',
          'language_id' => 1,
          'category_id' => 9,
          'created_at' => $now,
          'updated_at' => $now
        ],
        [
          'title' => 'Kreis 9',
          'language_id' => 2,
          'category_id' => 9,
          'created_at' => $now,
          'updated_at' => $now
        ],
        [
          'title' => 'Kreis 10',
          'language_id' => 1,
          'category_id' => 10,
          'created_at' => $now,
          'updated_at' => $now
        ],
        [
          'title' => 'Kreis 10',
          'language_id' => 2,
          'category_id' => 10,
          'created_at' => $now,
          'updated_at' => $now
        ],
        [
          'title' => 'Kreis 11',
          'language_id' => 1,
          'category_id' => 11,
          'created_at' => $now,
          'updated_at' => $now
        ],
        [
          'title' => 'Kreis 11',
          'language_id' => 2,
          'category_id' => 11,
          'created_at' => $now,
          'updated_at' => $now
        ],
        [
          'title' => 'Kreis 12 / Schwamendingen',
          'language_id' => 1,
          'category_id' => 12,
          'created_at' => $now,
          'updated_at' => $now
        ],
        [
          'title' => 'Kreis 12 / Schwamendingen',
          'language_id' => 2,
          'category_id' => 12,
          'created_at' => $now,
          'updated_at' => $now
        ]
      ];
      CategoryTranslations::create($arg2);

      $this->command->info(count($data).' article categories are created');
    }
```

Comment: Did you look at stack trace? You should get it with verbose mode - `php artisan db:seed -vvv`

Comment: Check the full error / stack trace for line number to narrow down the issue. Difficult to debug with a one-line error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**create()** method accepts an array of attributes for a single model. If you want to create multiple objects you need to **create()** muptiple times:

```
foreach($arg1 as $data) {
  Categories::create($data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `insert`

```
Categories::insert($arg1);
```